# Laravel Homestead on USB Drive

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I'm trying to set up a Laravel Homestead on a USB drive given the unfortunate amount of space on my laptop's disk. My current OS is Ubuntu 16.04. I've followed this tutorial:
https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/running-vagrant-virtualbox

My USB Drive has three directories:

- "vagrant_home", where I copied and renamed ".vagrant.d", as instructed by the tutorial. I successfully have a laravel/homestead box in here.
- "VirtualBox VMs", where I set VirtualBox to look for VMs.
- "Homestead", following the directions in the official Laravel tutorial, I cloned this git repository and changed one of the Homestead.yaml settings to reflect the USB Drive:

`folders:
    - map: /media/nick/Homestead/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code
      type: "nfs"`

When I run "vagrant up", an unwanted .vagrant.d folder is created in my home directory, not on the USB drive. Additionally, I get this error:

```
There was an error while executing 'VBoxManage', a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["hostonlyif", "create"]

Stderr: 0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: VBoxNetAdpCtl: ioctl failed for /dev/vboxnetctl: Inappropriate ioctl for devic
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreate(HandlerArg*)" at line 94 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
`
```

I have also installed Vagrant and VirtualBox, as described by the official Homestead tutorial: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead

Thanks for reading. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: does that help https://askubuntu.com/questions/787471/virtualbox-5-is-unable-to-create-a-host-only-adapter-on-ubuntu-16-04 ?

Comment: Similar to the person who commented under the solution in that thread, I get 'EFI variables are not supported on this system' while running mokutil. But thanks for digging that up! Glad to know I'm not alone with this issue.

Comment: then https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91623/216125

Comment: I looked into that, but efivars doesn't seem to be accessible in terminal on Ubuntu like it is on Arch. Niether is efivarfs as suggested by a comment on that thread. Accessing efivars seems to be it's own little rabbit hole.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting virtual box or vagrant reload command.

Make sure its not a permission issue

Comment: I powered off and powered on Vagrant reload throws the same error as above. Tried reinstalling the whole thing as root. No success. Not sure how to properly restart VirtualBox on Ubuntu, but it seems to be turning on and off properly based on service monitoring.